# cURL Access Denied in crawler PHP

Tags: php, curl, web-crawler

I'm creating a crawler to capture some public information.
However, it is returning:

> Access Denied 
> You don't have permission to access "http://www.americanas.com.br/" on this server.

Using Postman to test a request, cURL works perfectly. I even got the code generated by Postman (as shown below), but when I use it directly on my PHP server, return the error informed above.

My cURL code:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.americanas.com.br/",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "cache-control: no-cache",
        "postman-token: 112ebf89-1bb7-aa7a-0645-cdeabcf96488"
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if($err) echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
else echo $response;
exit();
```

Comment: When I go to the URL https://www.americanas.com.br/ in my browser, I get the same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that there are sites with more complex locks. In these cases, it is necessary to use more complete crawler solutions.
The one I'm using and is working is Proxycawl (https://proxycrawl.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Your postman is querying **https**://www.americanas.com.br/ while from the error message we can suppose that in your crawler you are querying **http**://www.americanas.com.br/

Comment: As per my cURL code, I'm using "httpS". Maybe the redirect is automatic, I don't know why